# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf composite form backing beans

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Lets have two form-backing classes.

```
Person
  - name (String)
  - surname (String)

Application
  - reason (String)
  - date   (Date)
  - person (Person)
```

and a Thymeleaf fragment which renders html form for a `Person` object like this:

```
<input name="name"/>
<input name="surname"/>
```

Is there a posibility to reuse the same fragment in the fragment which renders `Application` html form with the expected result:

```
<input name="reason"/>
<input name="date"/>
<input name="person.name"/>
<input name="person.surname"/>
```

In other words can Thymeleaf form fragment be used universally in the case when `Person` is the top level form backing bean and also in the case when it is part of other form backing bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use prefix and pass it to your template. I hope you like the idea. In the code below the application fragment can also be prefixed and included in another form. I have not tested the code. If something is wrong just let me know. I use such a construction in my code.

```
<th:block th:fragment="person">
  Name:<input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix + 'name'}__}" /> 
  Surname:<input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix + 'surname'}__}" />
</th:block>

<th:block th:fragment="application">
  Reason:<input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix + 'reason'}__}" /> 
  Date:<input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix + 'date'}__}" />
  <div th:replace="fragments/forms :: person" th:with="prefix=${prefix +'person.'}">
</th:block>
```